# Realm in SwiftUI: Live Text in UI for Object Only Saved Occasionally

Tags: swiftui, realm, combine

I'm doing a comparison of Core Data and Realm in a SwiftUI app, and Core Data does something that I'm hoping to figure out how to do in Realm.

Core Data lets you mutate objects whenever you want, and when they are `ObservableObject` in SwiftUI, your UI instantly updates. You then save the `context` whenever you want to persist the changes.

In Realm, the objects in the UI are live, but you can't change them unless you are in a write transaction. I'm trying to get my UI to reflect live/instant changes from the user when the actual `write` is only performed occasionally. Below is a sample app.

Here's my Realm model:

```
import RealmSwift

class Item: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable{
  @objc dynamic var recordName = ""
  @objc dynamic var text = ""

  override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "recordName"
  }
}
```

Here is my view model that also includes my `save()` function that only saves **every 3 seconds**. In my actual app, this is because it's an expensive operation and doing it as the user types brings the app to a crawl.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
  static let shared = ViewModel()
  @Published var items: Results<Item>!
  @Published var selectedItem: Item?
  
  var token: NotificationToken? = nil
  
  init(){
    //Add dummy data
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.beginWrite()
    
    let item1 = Item()
    item1.recordName = "one"
    item1.text = "One"
    realm.add(item1, update: .all)
    
    let item2 = Item()
    item2.recordName = "two"
    item2.text = "Two"
    realm.add(item2, update: .all)
    
    try! realm.commitWrite()
    
    self.fetch()
    
    //Notifications
    token = realm.objects(Item.self).observe{ [weak self] _ in
      self?.fetch()
    }
  }
  
  //Get Data
  func fetch(){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    self.items = realm.objects(Item.self)
  }
  
  //Save Data
  var saveTimer: Timer?
  func save(item: Item, text: String){
    //Save occasionally
    saveTimer?.invalidate()
    saveTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false){ _ in
      
      let realm = try! Realm()
      try? realm.write({
        item.text = text
      })
      
    }
  }
  
}
```

Last of all, here is the UI. It's pretty basic and reflects the general structure of my app where I'm trying to pull this off.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var model = ViewModel.shared
  
  var body: some View {
   
    VStack{
      ForEach(model.items){ item in
        HStack{
          Button(item.text){
            model.selectedItem = item
          }
          Divider()
          ItemDetail(item: item)
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

...and the ItemDetail view:

```
struct ItemDetail: View{
  @ObservedObject var item: Item
  @StateObject var model = ViewModel.shared
  
  init(item: Item){
    self.item = item
  }
  
  var body: some View{
    //Binding
    let text = Binding<String>(
      get: { item.text },
      set: { model.save(item: item, text: $0) }
    )
    
    TextField("Text...", text: text)
      .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
  }
}
```

When I type in the `TextField`, how do I get the `Button` text to reflect what I have typed **in real time** considering that my `realm.write` only happens **every 3 seconds**? My `Button` updates after a write, but I want the UI to respond live--independent of the write.

Comment: Is this a Multi-User App or a Single User App? Also, it's not clear why you're fetching your objects and when there's a change, you're fetching them again. The change will be reflected in the objects automatically and *what* changed will be reflected in the notification. Why are you writing to Realm every 3 seconds? What's preventing you from simply updating the button text with the text in the field as the user types? Realm is not needed for that at all.

Comment: This is a multi-user app (though I'm not using Realm Sync if that's what you're referring to).

Comment: I fetch again when there are changes because it's simpler than processing individual changes.

Comment: I'm writing every few seconds because the text that's entered is processed and converted to Base64 and doing so with each keystroke is super slow (I have to wait several seconds for each letter I type to appear).

Comment: If I don't need Realm to reflect the updated text, that's great. But I'm unclear how. Do I set up a binding and somehow reconcile its value with what is saved to Realm? The gist of my question is how to do something like that.

Comment: If this is a multi-user app then Core Data is probably wrong solution as there is no shared 'server' as such. But as you mentioned, there may be other components involved. You do not need to 'fetch' data from Realm again - it's done automatically. Results always reflect the current state of the data. Processing changes is *the* way to go, it could be even just a reload of a tableView. Why are you processing and converting text with each keystroke, moreover that's done in code and should be imperceptible to the user, if it's not, something else is wrong. What's the purpose of that conversion?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using CloudKit to sync the data between users. That part is already working. The example above is a contrived tiny piece of the actual code I have. I find that if I don't fetch again, my `@Published` variables don't update in my views.

Comment: The text is typed in a `WKWebView` using https://quilljs.com. That rich text editor converts the text to a JSON object, and I convert that object to Base64 so I can store it as a string in Realm. I then sync it to other devices and the Web.

Comment: My goodness! Your jumping through a LOT of really unnecessary hoops - no wonder it's slow. Ok, so.. You need to get your Realm code straightened out first. See [Realm SwiftUI](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/integrations/swiftui/#std-label-ios-swiftui-combine-quick-start). You should not be loading and reloading realm just to see the changes - take note of `ObservedRealmObject` in the `ItemDetailsView` section. Also see the `struct ItemsView` and note the bound `$group.items.append(Item())` which automatically handles write transactions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231671/discussion-between-clifton-labrum-and-jay).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggested documentation from `Jay`, I got the following to work which is quite a bit simpler:

My main view adds the `@ObservedResults` property wrapper like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var model = ViewModel.shared
  @ObservedResults(Item.self) var items

  var body: some View {
   
    VStack{
      ForEach(items){ item in
        HStack{
          Button(item.text){
            model.selectedItem = item
          }
          Divider()
          ItemDetail(item: item)
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

...and then the `ItemDetail` view simply uses an `@ObservedRealmObject` property wrapper that binds to the value in Realm and manages the writes automatically:

```
struct ItemDetail: View{
  @ObservedRealmObject var item: Item

  var body: some View{
    TextField("Text...", text: $item.text)
      .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
  }
}
```

This is essentially how Core Data does it (in terms view code) except Realm saves to the store automatically. Thank you, Jay!

Comment: Oh man! Way to go! Super happy you have a solution.

Comment: I'll add that this works really nicely in my contrived example, but I am struggling with two things in more complex implementations: (1) I'd rather have my `Results` defined in, and read from, a view model. (2) How can I perform more complex queries on an `@ObservedResults` using `.filter()` and `.sorted()`?